# Problem about function decomposition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Let $f(x)\in C[0,+\infty)$, and for any non-negative real number $a$, we have $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} (f(x+a)-f(x))=0.$$Prove that exist $g(x)\in C[0,+\infty)$ and $h(x)\in C^1[0,+\infty)$, such that $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, where $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=0,\quad \lim_{x\to+\infty} h'(x)=0.$$**
I have try using function approximation, but fail to solve it.